# How can I find out which version of Cassandra a specific DSE is running?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax

So far, I haven't found a place on Datastax documentation website that sums this up. Can I easily check the version some other way on a server?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Open cqlsh and type `show VERSION`.

This gives all the versions of cqlsh, DSE, Cassandra etc.

[image: Version details]

```
admin@cqlsh> SELECT cql_version FROM system.local;

 cql_version
-------------
       3.4.0
```

Also, `nodetool version` shows the Cassandra version

Comment: That output is very easily parsed. So, instead of opening the interactive `cqlsh`, just do `cqlsh -e "show VERSION"` and pipe that where ever.

Comment: @Arun,  how did you managed to get both Cassandra and DSE in cqlsh ? What kind of installation have you performed?

Comment: ...only if its running, not in a build pipeline for example.

Answer (score 48):

I'm not sure if there is an explicit page that shows cassandra version by DSE release, but the 'Release Notes' page of each DSE release shows the versions that are installed.  For example, here are the [Release Notes for 4.5](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/RNdse45.html) which show all versions including cassandra that are upgraded at each minor version.

One way to check against running Cassandra instances by running the following queries in cqlsh:

```sql
select peer, release_version from system.peers;
select release_version from system.local;
```

This first query will return all hosts and their release version except for the local node being queried.  The second query will return it for the local node being queried.

Example output:

```
cqlsh> select peer, release_version from system.peers;

 peer      | release_version
-----------+-----------------
 127.0.0.3 |  2.1.2-SNAPSHOT
 127.0.0.1 |  2.1.2-SNAPSHOT

(2 rows)

cqlsh> select release_version from system.local;

 release_version
-----------------
 2.1.2-SNAPSHOT

(1 rows)
```

Comment: You can also know the version by simply opening cqlsh. You should see something like `[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.11.83 | DSE 4.6.0 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]` as part of the "welcome messages" upon connecting to a node via cqlsh

Comment: That's a good point, even better for getting the local version!

Answer (score 16):

Simply do bin/cassandra -v , it will work even if cassandra is already running. Same -v option if you are using the service version instead of the tarball.

Comment: Thanks, in centos6 it is like this: `/usr/sbin/cassandra -v`

Comment: In Ubuntu-20.04 it is also `/usr/sbin/cassandra -v`

Comment: on Ubuntu 20.04, `cassandra -v` works too.

Answer (score 11):

This table maps DS versions to Cassandra versions: http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibilityDocument.html

Comment: Nice, wonder how recent that doc is since I've never seen it.  It doesn't give the full version, but having Major DSE Version <-> Major C* Version is good information to have.

Answer (score 2):

also if you are running opscenter, on the dashboard page, you can look at what version of DSE and what version of Cassandra your nodes are running

Answer (score 2):

Just run `select * from system.local;` in Datastax studio cql section. It gives all the  details. And to know compatibility with apache cassandra version, please refer this datastax documentation [page here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibility.html)